# folder is not shown in docker container after COPY instruction

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have this docker-compose:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y doxygen graphviz

COPY doc /abc/doc
COPY src /abc/src

WORKDIR /abc

RUN doxygen doc/Doxyfile

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=0 /abc/doc/doxyglsen/html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

But there is no folder `abc` in my container, in `/usr/share/nginx/html` everything ok  :
[image]

Whats a problem?

Still have an error with this

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y doxygen graphviz
COPY doc /abc/doc
COPY src /abc/src
WORKDIR /abc
RUN doxygen doc/Doxyfile
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY doc /abc/doc
COPY src /abc/src
COPY --from=0 /abc/doc/doxyglsen/html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Error in last step :

```
Step 10/10 : COPY --from=0 /abc/doc/doxyglsen/html /usr/share/nginx/html
ERROR: Service 'node' failed to build : COPY failed: stat abc/doc/doxyglsen/html: file does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image built by `FROM ubuntu:16.04` and one by `FROM nginx:alpine` are different. The former has `/abc/doc` and `/abc/src` but the latter doesn't. The former is dropped when the latter has been finished to build.

Comment: Ok i removed 2 last lines in `Dockerfile`, but my container doesn`t start. Why?

Comment: That doesn't make image which contains nginx. Don't remove part of statements for nginx, but add for `COPY doc /abc/doc` and `COPY src /abc/src` again in nginx image.

Comment: Body of question was updated. Tell me pls where is a mistake.

Comment: Ah, just a typo. Please forget what I said. `/abc/doc/doxyglsen/html` is wrong, but `/abc/doc/doxygen/html` is correct. Sorry.